# Fixed position causes my header to be pushed to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My header takes the full width of its container when I dont have it fixed.

```css
html {
    font-size: 32px;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'IM Fell French Canon SC', serif;
    text-align: right;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

When I do fix my header, the right side it gets pushed out of the page:

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}
```

Is there any other proper way to do it without adding padding to the right to offset the change?

HTML CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative:wght@700&family=IM+Fell+French+Canon+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Watch iT</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header Section -->
    <header>
        <span id="logo">W</span>
        <nav>
            <span><a href="#">About</a></span>
            <span><a href="#">Products</a></span>
            <span><a href="#">Contact</a></span>
        </nav>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: @TannerDolby updated

Comment: See fixed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values), the element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport.

> If you specify `width:100%`, the element’s total width will be 100% of its containing block plus any horizontal margin, padding and border (unless you’ve used box-sizing:border-box, in which case only margins are added to the 100% to change how its total width is calculated).

The combination of `width: 100%` and `position: fixed` on the `header` is the cause for nav menu items overflowing out the right side of the page in the flex container. This is because `width: 100%` is allowing content to be larger than its containing block and overflow. If you add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the page then the overflow issue is resolved. Also, you can set a `top` and `left` position for the fixed position container to specify offsets from the edges of the element's [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block).

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 32px;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'IM Fell French Canon SC', serif;
    text-align: right;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative:wght@700&family=IM+Fell+French+Canon+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Watch iT</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header Section -->
    <header>
        <span id="logo">W</span>
        <nav>
            <span><a href="#">About</a></span>
            <span><a href="#">Products</a></span>
            <span><a href="#">Contact</a></span>
        </nav>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use fixed position you need to have reference points so that the elemnt knows where it is fixed to. This should be fixed by adding:

```css
header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This will attach the element to the top right part of the screen. Since the element is fixed, the width might be wonky as well. If the header is in a fullscreen header, just go with `width: 100vw`

### Relative to another container

If your element needs to be fixed relative to another element and have the same width, the parent element NEEDS to have `position: relative;`

This tells your component what to use as a reference when it is placed absolutely. Having top and left 0 will anchor it to the top left corner of the relative element, and width 100% will have it take the width of the relative container.